# How i can open a form in popup for edit mode within repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, jquery

I am developing web application in which I used repeater to create a grid and I bind a link for edit page when user clicks on that link then ID of that specific record passed to that page and all relevant information extracted from database for that ID and displayed in text boxes.
Now i have to use Popup for edit form what should i do now? i used [Ajaxtoolkit model popup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) but unfortunately I did not get id of that link on which user clicks so that i can load data against that ID?

Comment: You can fetch the id of clicked repeater from serverside using e.item.index from the repeater event, then through querystring you can pass the id to Ajax modal popup form

Answer (score 1):

Just use javascript to popup the window and pass the id to the javascript function. Do it like this:

Javascript Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PopupEdit(RecordID) {
    window.open("EditPagePath.aspx?id=" + RecordID, "EditPageWindow", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=600");
}</script>
```

On Repeater Item:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PopupEdit('<%# Eval("RecordID") %>')">Edit</a>
```

Good Luck!